# The difference between two Stat functions for wilcoxon test

Tags: r, pairwise

I know that the main difference between stats::wilcox.test and stats::pairwise.wilcox.test is computing p.adjust value. This value is only computed by stats::pairwise.wilcox.test in one step. but there is something wired when I get an error with the following code. I expect to get the same results but it gets the error of group size?!

```
df <- dataframe(group = c(rep("before",5), rep("after",5)),
                a = runif(1:10),
                b = runif(1:10),
                c = runif(1:10))
#wilcox.test withour error
df %>%
   summarise_each(funs(wilcox.test(.[group == "before"], .[group == "after"], 
                                   paired = TRUE)$p.value), vars = a:c)

#pairwise.wilcox.test with error
df %>%
   summarise_each(funs(pairwise.wilcox.test(.[group == "before"], .[group == "after"])), 
                  vars = a:c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues. Thus, I would try this:

First check the functions and results using simply subsetting

```
wilcox.test(a ~ group, df)
pairwise.wilcox.test(df$a, df$group, p.adjust.method = "none")
```

Then, try a `tidyverse`:

```
df %>% 
  gather(key, value, -group) %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  summarise(pvalue = wilcox.test(value ~ group)$p.value)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  key   pvalue
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 a     0.0916
2 b     0.386 
3 c     0.969
```

There is absolutly no need to use the pairwise version since there are only two group values in your data. 
If you stick on summarize, try

```
df %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(-1), list(~wilcox.test(. ~ group)$p.value))
           a         b         c
1 0.09155406 0.3858534 0.9693262
```

Used Data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(group = c(rep("before",5), rep("after",5)),
                a = runif(50),
                b = runif(50),
                c = runif(50))
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, could you please tell me what's wrong with my codes?

Comment: It starts at `runif(1:10)`, which is ok since `n` is allowed to be a vector but it is recommended to be a number of length one and ends in the subsetting using `[group == "before"]`. Which of course works but is completely rubbish in the wilcox functions. try the help `?runif()`